# print_r values of an Array in $_POST

Tags: php, post

I have got a question regarding printing an array of checkboxes in the $_POST
When I do:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

I can see the Checkboxes which I send through the $_POST
How am I able to read only the checkboxes?
This is what I currently have:

```
print_r($_POST['checkboxes[]']);
```

But this doesn't seem to work

Comment: `$_POST['checkboxes']`

Comment: If the name of the input is in fact checboxes, remove the squares []

Comment: Your dealing with the field names and not their types.

Comment: I don't know why, but this didn't solve the problem in first place. Probably some cache? it however did now. Thank you very much!! @BartScheffer

Comment: if you variable is array, dont include '[]' on POST like this $_POST['checkboxes']

Answer (score 1):

If your checkboxes actually have their `name='checkboxes[]'`, then you can access their POST value by doing `print_r($_POST['checkboxes']);`. You do not have to include the square brackets when referencing the name of the POST value, the brackets are only there make all of the same named elements post as an array.